# Validate WCF user based on URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

If I have a wcf rest service such as http://somedomain.com/service.svc/uniqueid/somemethod/parameter1
then is there a way to globally check if the uniqueid is valid for every request hitting the server.
I could put in a check for every operation contract but I'm looking for a way where this is not needed so that everytime the service is accessed the uniqueid is checked and does not proceed if invalid.

Just for some further background as to what I'm trying to achieve... The WCF service is an open API. Getting a uniqueid is also open and requires no kind of signup. I want to use the uniqueid so if the API is abused I can easily pull 1 ID's access without affecting any of the other users of the system.

UPDATE:Based on Mike's Suggestion I've created an IParameterInspector

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class IDParameterInspector : Attribute, IParameterInspector
```

And attached it to my Service class

```
[IDParameterInspector]
public class MetaData : IMetaData
```

The problem I now have is the ApplyDispatchBehavior never runs.

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            if (channelDispatcher == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            foreach (var endPoint in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                if (endPoint == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                foreach (var operation in endPoint.DispatchRuntime.Operations)
                {
                    operation.ParameterInspectors.Add(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone now what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is that unique id specified?

Comment: It's just a GUID that's passed into the URL.I have a list of ID's in a database and to validate I simply check the uniqueID passed via the URL is present in the database. Instead of making this check in every operation contract I was hoping there was a more global way to achieve this. Also I know passing via the URL means it's not secure but this doesn't matter.

Comment: have you looked at parameterinspectors?

Comment: It really depends on your implementation, but you could put the ID in the message header and then you can add a custom message inspector to your servicehost and check the header of every incoming message.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMiller - I've had a stab with a parameter inspector but think I'm doing something wrong. Could you look at the updated code above? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to use a parameter inspector and custom behaviour via attributes.  You need to unfortunately implement both.

So starting with the decoration of the service method in the interface

```
[MyFirstCustomBehavior()]
string SayHello(string language);
```

We then need to define the MyFirstCustomBehavior class.

```
internal sealed class MyFirstCustomBehavior : Attribute, System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior
{

    #region IOperationBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        //no special behaviour
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(new MyFirstCustomParameterInspector());
    }

    public void Validate(System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
        //no special behaviour
    }

    #endregion
}
```

We then need to code up the inspector.

```
internal sealed class MyFirstCustomParameterInspector : System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IParameterInspector
{
    #region IParameterInspector Members

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
        ////do stuff here
    }

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        ////or here
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You should then be good to go.

Comment: Thank's Mark, This worked but then I also got my version working. I forgot to put class IServiceBehavior after IDParameterInspector : Attribute, IParameterInspector - Using this approach you combine the behaviour and attribute into one class that you can then assign to the Service instead of every service method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a **custom service behavior** that will affect all the incoming requests.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37280/WCF-Service-Behavior-Example-IPFilter-Allow-Deny-A) is an example that filters the requests based upon IP address and you can use that as a reference. If I get some time I'll post some code.